# Tip on turn based game AI

Tags: ai, design-patterns, turn-based, turn-based-strategy

I'm quite new in video game AI, and I'm trying to design an AI for a turn based game.

The rules are simple:

- The battle field is represented by an NxM board.
- The game is between two team, each team has X character.
- Each character, based on his type, can move within  C cells and can attack within A cells.
- On each turn a player can move and then attack (not attack and then move ) with each one of the caracter in his team (time limit).

I'm thinking on how design the AI for this kind of game.

One solution I have thought is a Multi Agent System composed by two kind of agents:
The first one *charachert Agent* calculate on each step a function SCORE for each of the cells reachable by the character, and the second one, *team Agent* calculate the new position for each character based on the score calculated by the former agent. Each character can then attack an opponent if there is one reachable.

Is it a good solution?

Can someone suggest a different solution or give me some tips?

Comment: How are you going to calculate the score of each cell? And what does the team agent do what the character agent can't do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549986/writing-an-ai-for-a-turn-based-board-game Not a straight copy of your question but the answer there is really complete, you might get some infos from that !

Comment: @Philipp I was thinking on how to do it. The basic idea is to calculate a function influenced by some factors as: enemy position (number reachable opponent characters), character health, opponent reachable character health, characher and opponent weapon power and so on. So mixing some of those values I should have a "score" for each cells. It is only a basic idea I'm still studing how to do it.

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet  it is a really good answer. Anyway I was trying to avoid algorithm as minimax or A* because  I think the generated tree (even if I cut) could be really huge (each team can move or attach with all the character each turn). And this is basically one of my questions...is this assumption (huge decision tree) wrong?